# How to use a persistent H2 database in the Play Framework instead of in-memory

Tags: database, playframework, playframework-2.0, h2

The H2 database used in the Java Todo List tutorial is the following:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

How do I modify the configuration file to use a persistent database as opposed to an in-memory version. Do I need to setup an entirely separate DB or can I modify the `db.default.url` property?

I'm using Play! 2.0.3.

Answer (score 29):

I found the solution.

To create a file database, modify the following:

From

```
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

To

```
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:file:data/db"
```

Where `data/db` is broken down into:

`data/` The folder location of the database files relative to your project root.

`db` The name of your database files.

Comment: The `data/db` is in fact relative to the directory where the process is started. This is a problem if the process is not always started from the same directory. Instead I suggest to use `jdbc:h2:file:~/data/db`. This will create the database file relative to the home directory of the current user.