# Spring h2-console not opening

Tags: java, h2

I am trying to open my h2-console on my spring boot app, but its giving me "Whitelabel Error Page".
I have configured my application.properties file

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Added dependencies for h2 db:

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.200</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

tried rebuilding project and checked for https automatic redirecting

Comment: Maybe try to add this `spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console` to your `application.properties` and access it by `http://localhost:port/h2-console` I also notice that you have your dependency on `test scope` ??? Maybe change it to `runtime`

Comment: removed test scope and i added that to properties still not working... tried using full url before and it looks its not because of https redirecting problem on google chrome

Comment: One more question why you have two dependencies for `h2`? I would keep only the the `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: <scope>runtime</scope> solved problem .. sry if this is stupid question but can i mark comment same like i can mark answers that i solved problem... if not write all of that to answer Aristotle so i can mark it and give you upvote :)

Comment: I will write an answer as well. So someone else could find it :) glad I helped

Comment: one more question why it doesnt want to connect now when it showed

Comment: so when i try to connect to it using default url it gives me this "A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;FORBID_CREATION=TRUE". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-200] 90011/90011" @Aristotle

Comment: I believe that this will help [stackoverflow-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596150/how-to-use-a-path-relative-to-project-root-to-h2-db-file-configuration-with-play)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a dependency with `<scope>test</scope>` it indicates that the dependency
is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases

So change it to `runtime` because this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. Maven includes a dependency with this scope in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

This will solve your issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You can read more about scopes [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your H2 Dependency from test to runtime

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```